# php get the value of a keyed paired that matches

Tags: php, arrays

I want to be able to input "checkout-method" and return "pickup"
but checkout_method can be in any position in the array below.
I just cant figure it out.

```
[{
                "name": "Checkout-Method",
                "value": "pickup"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-Id",
                "value": "87704"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Date",
                "value": "2020\/04\/01"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-Company",
                "value": "Combo Box Peoria"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-Address-Line-1",
                "value": "8990 West Windsor Drive"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-City",
                "value": "Peoria"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-Region",
                "value": "Arizona"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-Postal-Code",
                "value": "85381"
            }, {
                "name": "Pickup-Location-Country",
                "value": "United States"
            }, {
                "name": "Curbside-Note",
                "value": "Chevrolet Suburban white"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: What's the problem? Use a `foreach` loop, check the name, and return the value if it's the one you want.

Comment: It would be easier if you used a single array instead of 2-dimensional array.

Comment: that is the json data returned from a website. It is what I have to work with.

Comment: OK, then just write the loop. `foreach ($data as $element) { ... }`

Comment: If `$element['name']` is the name you're looking for, return `$element['value']`. Real basic stuff.